# How to write angular test case to cover array.find()

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to write test case for the below method. I have written something like below but it does not improve /change code coverage. Can someone please help what I am doing wrong?

**Component**

```
remove(item: string, element:any){
    const found =  this.list1.find(el => el.team == element.tirname);
    if(found){
    var index = this.list1.indexOf(found);
    if (index >= 0) {
    this.list1[index].removeFlag = true;
    const index1= this.list1[index].orgsUpdated.indexOf(item);
    if (index1 >= 0) {
      this.list1[index]['orgsUpdated'].splice(index1, 1);
      this.list1[index]['removeFlag'] = false;
      
    }
   
  }
}
const found1 =  this.list2.find(el => el.name == element.name);
if(found1){
var index2 = this.list2.indexOf(found1);
  if (index2 >= 0) {
    const index1= this.list2[index2].gOrgNames.indexOf(item);
    if (index1 >= 0) {
      this.list2[index]['gitOrganizationNames'].splice(index1, 1);
      
    }
   
  }
}
```

}

**Spec file**

```
it('should call remove', () => {
  const spySubscribable = spyOn(component, 'remove');
 let index = 0;
 let item = "org1";
 let element = [{
        "team": 'team1',
        "orgsUpdated": ["org1", "org2"],
        "removeFlag":false
    }];
  component.remove(item,element);
  component.list1[index] = element;
  component.list1[index].removeFlag = true;
  expect(component.list1[index].removeFlag).toBeTruthy;
  expect(spySubscribable).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.list1[0]).toEqual(element);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `spyOn(component, 'remove')` spies on the method to see how many times it was called and removes its implementation details. To keep its implementation details, add a `.and.callThrough()` after the `spyOn`.

Something like this:

```
it('should call remove', () => {
  // change this line
  const spySubscribable = spyOn(component, 'remove').and.callThrough();
 let index = 0;
 let item = "org1";
 let element = [{
        "team": 'team1',
        "orgsUpdated": ["org1", "org2"],
        "removeFlag":false
    }];
  // add this log and see what the value is and make sure
  // this.list1.find returns something so it goes inside of the if 
  // block
  console.log('List 1: ', component.list1);
  component.remove(item,element);
  component.list1[index] = element;
  component.list1[index].removeFlag = true;
  expect(component.list1[index].removeFlag).toBeTruthy;
  expect(spySubscribable).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.list1[0]).toEqual(element);
});
```

Comment: I change it to callThrough() but still the code coverage is not covering the rest of the lines in the function. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe because `found` and `found1` are undefined and therefore don't go inside of the if statements. Try logging them when the function is called and see their values.

Comment: Yes may be but am not sure how to address this issue in test case. Can you pls help ? TIA

Comment: Try logging `list1` in the test. I have added an edit with a comment. You have to make sure that `if(found)` returns true.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this issue ! component.list1 does have an object in it. It returns  below values but still its not going inside found if loop.                                                                                                 {orgsUpdated:  ["org1", "org2"]
removeFlag: false
team: "team1"}

Comment: log out `element.tirname` (console.log(element.tirname)), I bet you it could be undefined and that's why the `.find` returns undefined.

Comment: That was it ! You are right...the element.tirname wasnt defined and that was the reason it wasnt going inside the found loop. Thank you so much again for helping and sticking throughout to resolve the issue.

Comment: if(res.message.length > 0){
            for(let i=0; i<res.message.length;i++){
            this.message = this.message +"\n" + res.message[i];
     }
    }
          else {
            this.message = 'Success'
          }
          this.service.getData(this.userid).subscribe((res)=>{
            this.responseData[index].names = res[index].names;
            this.temp1[index]['orng']=[];
            this.temp1[index]['flg'] = false;
            this.responseDataOriginal[index].names = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.responseData[index].names)));
          });
        
        }

Comment: can you pls help here? my spec code isnt getting inside first if loop.

Comment: Can you show the code snippet as an edit in your message? I am thinking we have to mock `res.message`.